# adding custom class by index in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As someone new to JS and jQuery, I'm working on a table with multiple columns that contain numbers, except for the last one which has text. My goal is to first add the "custom-sortable" class to all elements in the last column that equal the word "Camp", and then add the "custom-sortable" class to all elements in the entire table where the last column equals to "Camp". I've tried different approaches, but haven't had success. My latest idea is to use the index of elements in the last column that include the word "Camp". Any help or hints would be appreciated.

**Edit:** The table is a html, the class is just to change the background color of all elements equal to "Camp".

The following code works in terms of adding the class to the last column.

```
.custom-sortable .rank-list-item.rank-list-item-Camp {
    background-color: grey;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
            var targetIndex = -1;
            $('.custom-sortable .rank-list-item').each(function(index) {
            if ($(this).text() === 'Camp') {
            targetIndex = index;
            $(this).addClass('custom-sortable rank-list-item-Camp');
        }
        });
        if (targetIndex >= 0) {
        $('.custom-sortable .rank-list-item').eq(targetIndex).addClass('custom-sortable');
        }
        });
```

[image]

But i wish to end up with these results
[image]

Comment: And can you share a representative example of your `<table>` element's HTML? Both what you start with, and what you wish to end up with?

Comment: @DavidThomas i provided more info in the question

Comment: Thank you, but we need HTML not pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense to target the parent, instead of the child.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.custom-sortable').each(function(index) {
    let isCamp = false;

    $(this).find('.rank-list-item').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() === 'Camp') {
        isCamp = true;
        $(this).addClass('custom-sortable rank-list-item-Camp');
      }
    });

    if (isCamp) {
      $(this).addClass('custom-sortable');
    }
  });
});
```

This way you will find all of the rows that have "Camp" as the last cell, and  you don't need to keep track of the index in a separate variable (that will be overwritten.) You also don't need to traverse back up the parent after finding the child.

Comment: same here thank you but i have one one more question please, how can i modify your code to let work if  the data in multiple tables (not multiple columns in one table) each table with one column

Answer (score 2):

When you locate your target you can traverse up the DOM to the parent `tr` with [`.closest('tr')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). You can then target all the child `td`s with [`.find('td')`](https://api.jquery.com/find/). Here is an abbreviated snippet to demonstrate, but you only need to insert: `.closest('tr').find('td')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('td').each(function(index) {

    if ($(this).text() === 'Camp') {

      $(this).closest('tr').find('td').addClass('rank-list-item-Camp');

    }

  });

});
```

```css
.rank-list-item-Camp {
  background-color: grey;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Camp</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

P.S. If you are just starting to learn, then I would recommend just learning vanilla JavaScript (ES6+). jQuery is becoming obsolete and adds more weight than advantage anymore.

Comment: thank you, it works, just one more question please, how can i modify your code to let work if  the data in multiple tables (not multiple columns in one table) each table with one column

Comment: @BahgatNassour Open a new question for that

Comment: here is my second question , thanks in advance
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75743732/adding-custom-class-by-row-in-rshiny-using-jquery